# Changing name of parameters in AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Is it possible to change the name of the data parameters sent with AJAX dynamically?
For example:

```
let ParamName = `Post_${incremented_value}`;

$.post("index.php" { ParamName : "someValue" });
```

When viewing the request params the name is still ParamName.

Answer (score 1):

What you're essentially asking is:

> *How to set dynamic object property names?*

You can do this by adding them via square-bracket syntax.

```
let params = {};
params[ParamName] = 'someValue';
$.post("index.php" params);
```

You can also do it via `Object.defineProperty()` ([link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)):

```
Object.defineProperty(params, ParamName, {value: 'someValue'});
```